# Recursively typed function definition in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following type in typescript:

```
type wrapper<A extends Array<any> = []> = {
  chain<T extends string>(key: T): wrapper<[...A, T]>;
  x: A;
};
```

Inspired by the following challenge:
https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/blob/master/questions/12-medium-chainable-options/README.md

The idea is I would be able to do something like this:

```
let tmp = wrapper.chain('a').chain('b'); // Expected type wrapper<["a", "b"]>
```

However I am unable to implement the function definition, since it is meant to return a type of wrapper with a function definition for chain, that also needs to return a function etc...
Is it possible to implement this type in javascript with typesafety?

Comment: If you really want functions without classes you could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAjM4W) (which hides the implementation in an IIFE) and note that it is type safe (no type assertions needed).  Let me know if you want to see this written up as an answer or if you're happier with class constructors

Comment: @jcalz Thanks I prefer the version with functions, please do add it as one of the answers! also [...T] could be simplified to just T

Comment: [If you do that](https://tsplay.dev/m35M2w), then the compiler interprets the value `[]` as being of type `never[]` instead of type `[]`). I assume you want `wrapper` to be of type `Wrapper<[]>`, right?

Comment: nvm you are right the interpretation is bad without [...T] (I get never[])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use functions and plain objects, the easiest thing to do is write a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function (let's call it `w()`) that takes a value `value` of some `string[]` subtype `A` and produces a `Wrapper<T>`:

```
type Wrapper<A extends string[] = []> = {
    value: A;
    chain<T extends string>(key: T): Wrapper<[...A, T]>;
};

function w<A extends string[]>(value: A): Wrapper<A> {
    return {
        value,
        chain(key) {
            return w([...value, key]);
        }
    }
}
```

This is seen as type safe, because the compiler understands that a spread like `[...value, key]`  will produce a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) like `[...A, T]` when `T` is the type of `key`.  Then `wrapper` is just `w([])` where you pass in the empty tuple of type `[]`:

```
const empty: [] = []
const wrapper: Wrapper = w(empty);
    
const val = wrapper.chain("a").chain("b").chain("c").value;
// const val: ["a", "b", "c"]
console.log(val); // ["a", "b", "c"]
```

If you don't want to expose `w` and `empty`, you can use modules or namespaces where you just export `wrapper`, or you could write an [immediately invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression) to get the same effect:

```
const wrapper: Wrapper = (() => {
    function w<A extends string[]>(value: A): Wrapper<A> {
        return {
            value,
            chain(key) {
                return w([...value, key]);
            }
        }
    }
    const empty: [] = []
    return w(empty)
})();
```

Or even more simply:

```
const wrapper: Wrapper = (function w<A extends string[]>(value: A): Wrapper<A> {
    return {
        value,
        chain(key) {
            return w([...value, key]);
        }
    }
})([]);
```

Also note that if you're not careful, the value `[]` will be interpreted by the compiler as the type `never[]` instead of the tuple type `[]`.  One way to discourage that is to replace the array type `A` with a variadic tuple type `[...A]`; it means basically the same thing, but it gives the compiler a hint that you want a tuple type:

```
const wrapper = (function w<A extends string[]>(value: [...A]): Wrapper<A> {
    return {
        value,
        chain(key) {
            return w([...value, key]);
        }
    }
})([]);
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6gTgQzJOAeAglCAPYEB2AJgM5THBwCW+A5gNoC6UAvFIwHwtQDeAsAFBQhUAG4IANgFcIALijoA3AOFQAxgAsE1VABUsuAiTIVqNdgAoA1hBBydASjnwkKVHQB0n9ABooOhuxK-AC+QQL4CAC2EMRgCKrQAMqUkWDi0Hz8ysIAZpL4qsCUAPb4UADuGPp4RKTkVLQc5mJSsvKOsIjIEGjonJkqKnAQwJJwZQODUy3S3tlTKhpa+FY29jzzC1PDo+MV5h6eMxC+1iAM9kFbKsGbN5u3gsKqpeRYqaByjFyMmzhgxTgwDUr2B5S6KCcEJ6XHK5ggHxAlwEKKeQhe+DeLVh0Lg7iW1HMACIEET7PjNISiQAjMkU5bE1R045XYQAejZIMxwJaXxJRN8NIFUCJTIYmwxxGK6Xc4mKNGaEkuUA5bH5gtpgrFqMe4SiMTiCSgAEljQAxACiGzR+gBQK5b3BLh6UOdcC45nM62Y-TuuXyhRKZUqmBwNSM9VMTWOcnQHWc3V6vptWx2Ywmfuuogks0z1wJKzO60mWdTI3T+0O7mOpxsF1ZpeEj0bzYWramkuBCLAnzYTFYvxTwjTezh3dA9ge9i9YRtnez4hxbvpVNJ5ILxNp68pK1FzJzEAbKs5895atJGuFe-Fc9e0ogsvlivEytVdHVIs1Iu1WRCqNRETRLE8TQKaloAEzWio-yAsC85OomrqJh6eQFEUpQVFUYaGHUJiNAEz7SLG8a4hgyZlrsGZDtMB5zNRgwbkWUGNsO5ajgcnjVrRUBnPWeb3PR7ZQME06MMiv6LKCC5LomK67mucmbnSG57uSLKbKqp4SHyF6fleP6SZi96PgqLSvpy766UKWpEjeAi6r+AH6sBRpgRaADMzFCDB9rwbiKEBuhwZYQYtTGA09AETGbCcegFxIa4fReYMI5UY2Nb8c8O6rEiyWNqllacTWPF1uJLZ5kJIkHHxEnPFJ2KsAhKCKfy24MkKbVUkyakHkemn1dp55Xl+14SneMpyqZSoKMeQ2XjZdkhEAA)

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with classes and generics.  You could also go with using functions and returning objects, but I find it easier with classes.  Here's a possible solution:

```
class Wrapper<Item, Items extends unknown[] = []> {
  items: Items;

  constructor(items?: Items) {
    this.items = items as Items ?? [];
  }

  chain<T extends Item>(item: T): Wrapper<unknown extends Item ? T : T | Item, [...Items, T]> {
    return new Wrapper([...this.items, item]);
  }
}

const wrapper = new Wrapper<string>();

const tmp = wrapper.chain("a").chain("b"); // Wrapper<string, ["a", "b"]>
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/MYGwhgzhAEDqBOYAOSCm8A8BJALqgtgDTS4EyoAeeAdgCYwCu1A1tQPYDu1A2gLrQBeaHwB80AN4BYAFDRoASzz4IALhJKIAbhky5wNtQg54DYDjbwAFIrIB+NaWUBKCbrnQcAC3kQAdDeVBBQ1oSHUyaFtbYV5tWWgAXx144E8weWoMABVoShp6cPwRayU1LKc1BGQ0TCZWTmpcqlQ6GEdI6Byy6AAfQuJuXyHHCGIs3jEpeLl4VBwGeEbqVA44RBR0S0Ghrx9-DWIA3ic4uSTpc5l9QxxoDnWaoOXVqo3MI3gMgHNik+TrowefBIIL3aroXypdLUSwAIjAsKckLSGThACNEZpoAB6bFrcHvYzfAbw2HEWEYibJHAATzQJGoy3gQVeNQwH2JwlJ5MpYjyLQKrPQGAyADN0P0FNRxcyAGpgEAMVAQMTReWK5XQNTLABu6E0QA)

Then you can do the following to get the data within the tuple:

```
type Inner = Wrapper<string, ["a", "b"]> extends Wrapper<infer Item, infer Values> ? Values : never;
```

Edit: If you want to use functions, then you can just make a wrapper function that returns `new Wrapper<T>()`.